# Pytest ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, pytest

I have been looking for different issues and seems that pytest is having a issue with relative path.

Anywhere I am looking a solution is either to add the path of the project when importing modules on the test classes or running pytest as a module with `python -m pytest`

In Both cases im I am having the same issue with "no module named

```
python -m pytest 
======================================================================================== test session starts =========================================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.16, pytest-3.10.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /home/patrick/PycharmProjects/ScrapperController, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                         

=============================================================================================== ERRORS ===============================================================================================
___________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting app/tests/bank_model_test.py ____________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/patrick/PycharmProjects/ScrapperController/app/tests/bank_model_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py:709: in exec_
    exec("""exec _code_ in _globs_, _locs_""")
app/tests/bank_model_test.py:2: in <module>
    from app.bank_xpath import BankXpath
E   ImportError: No module named app.bank_xpath
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
====================================================================================== 1 error in 0.07 seconds =======================================================================================
```

The structure of my project is

```
project
project/app
project/app/bank_xpath.py
project/app/controller.py
project/tests
project/tests/bank_model_tests.py
```

This is a partial code how I am importing modules in the class.

```
import unittest
from app.bank_xpath import BankXpath
from app.dictionary import ERRORS


class TestingBanksModels(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_bank_wrong_iso(self):
        bankObject = create_correct_bank()
        bankObject.fromCurrency = "Danish Krones"
        error = [ERRORS["wrong_from_currency"]]
        self.assertEqual(bankObject.validate(), error)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using python2, I believe you'll need a file named `__init__.py` (it can be empty) in the `app/` directory in order for the import to work. I don't think this is an issue in python3.

Comment: Thanks, now I have a new error importing package. My bank_xpath.py is using a package called validators 'import validators'. Now it says it can not find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just updated python to 3.7 and solved all my issues. I though I was using python3 already... Thanks!